# c# - "Loop-animation" through a string list

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'm building a very simple C# WPF Application. What the app does is that when I press a button it shows a value randomly from an string list.

What I would like to achieve is a animation where it quickly scrolls through all the values from the list (displaying in a label) and then start to slow down and stop on a random string from the list. Almost as a "spinning/scrolling/flashing wheel of text".

I'm still very new to programming (second day of C# learning) so would be glad if someone could point me in the right direction. Loop with timer?

```
List<string> randomStrings = new List<string>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            randomString.Add("Abcd");
            randomString.Add("Water");
            randomString.Add("Moon");
            randomString.Add("Pizza");
            randomString.Add("Winter");
            randomString.Add("Orange");

            MyRandomStrings.ItemsSource = randomString; //Showing which strings in box.
        }

        public void GetRandomString()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int index = r.Next(randomString.Count);
            string myRandomString = randomString[index]; //Fetch a random string
        
            Result.Content = myRandomString; //Sets the label. I want this to be "animated".
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GetRandomString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Task.Delay` to create a delay and still create sequential code instead of a statemachine or timers etc.

Here is an example:

It uses a Label and a Button on a WindowsForm. So with a little ajustment, you can make it work on your configuration.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    private List<string> _randomStrings = new List<string>();
    private Random _rnd = new Random(DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _randomStrings.Add("Abcd");
        _randomStrings.Add("Water");
        _randomStrings.Add("Moon");
        _randomStrings.Add("Pizza");
        _randomStrings.Add("Winter");
        _randomStrings.Add("Orange");
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // determine the rollcount. (some initial rolls for the rolling effect)
        int rollCount = 50 + _rnd.Next(_randomStrings.Count);

        int index = 0;

        // roll it.......
        for (int i = 0; i < rollCount; i++)
        {
            // just use a modulo on the i to get an index which is inside the list.
            index = i % _randomStrings.Count;

            // display the current item
            label1.Text = _randomStrings[index];

            // calculate a delay which gets longer and longer each roll.
            var delay = (250 * i / rollCount);

            // wait some. (but don't block the UI)
            await Task.Delay(delay);
        }

        MessageBox.Show($"and.... The winner is... {_randomStrings[index]}");
    }
}
```

Comment: It works exactly as I wanted. I tried a bit with Stopwatch but it blocks/hangs the whole UI. Task.Delay was something new for me. Thanks Jeroen.

Comment: That's the power of async/await. Writing sequential code, run it as a statemachine. ;-)   _Don't forget to block a second execution (because you can press the button multiple times and the execution will be mixed up.)_